# How do documentation generators work?

Tags: documentation, javadoc, doxygen, documentation-generation

I'm trying to understand how documentation generators like Doxygen, JavaDocs etc. work. Please don't get me wrong, I'm not asking how to use them, but how they do it. I tried to find information about the topic but only found 1 article which is really old, so I'm kinda frustrated.

Does someone know any articles or literature about this?

Comment: I think you need to be a bit more specific, *what* about them is it that you don't understand? Do you understand compilers? Parsing/lexing?

Comment: Hi unwind, thanks for your reply. I know a little bit about compilers, parsing etc but to be honest I should refresh my mind on these topics. First I would only like to get a general idea about how they work, so I know on what topics I should read more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For doxygen there is a [manual page about the internals of Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/arch.html).

Some small document generators just use regular expressions to extract the documentation. The more flexible and complicated way is to develop a parser for the language and a parser for the documentation syntax just like doxygen and Javadoc do.